# How can I roll back the Terraform state of my config in S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform

I've messed up the Terraform state of a config, so I'd like to replace the existing state with a previous version. The state is stored in S3, and I'm using a lock table. Here's what I tried:

1. I downloaded an old version of the state from S3 and uploaded it to S3, replacing the existing version. Result of `tf plan`:

   ```
   Error: Error loading state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content.

   This may be caused by unusually long delays in S3 processing a previous state
   update.  Please wait for a minute or two and try again. If this problem
   persists, and neither S3 nor DynamoDB are experiencing an outage, you may need
   to manually verify the remote state and update the Digest value stored in the
   DynamoDB table to the following value: XXXXXX
   ```
2. I updated the digest value stored in the DynamoDB table. Result of `tf plan`:

   ```
   Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...

   Error: Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: ConditionalCheckFailedException: The conditional request failed
     status code: 400, request id: XXXXXXX
   Lock Info:
     ID:        XXXXXXX
     Path:      XXXXXX
     Operation: OperationTypePlan
     Who:       XXXXXX
     Version:   0.10.8
     Created:   2017-11-07 23:54:50.505166265 +0000 UTC
     Info:      


   Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
   by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
   again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
   flag, but this is not recommended.
   ```

How can I roll back/revert/recover/restore the Terraform state to an older version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try [force unlock](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/force-unlock.html) command? It works for me when dealing with the locking issue.

```
terraform force-unlock LOCK_ID
```

The lock id is the id in above output:

```
ID:        XXXXXXX
```

Updated by @alexsandarT

If this does not work, use `terraform force-unlock -force LOCK_ID`

Comment: If this does not work, use terraform force-unlock -force LOCK_ID - which worked for me